# iPad / iframe: box-shadow doesn't work when position is fixed

Tags: css, ios, ipad

In iPad an iframe doesn't display the shadow properly if its position is fixed.

`position: fixed`  http://jsfiddle.net/akRsC/

`position: static` http://jsfiddle.net/akRsC/1/

Anyone knows how to fix this aside from removing `position:fixed`?

EDIT:
For some reason, the shadow is displayed when viewing the example inside jsfiddle but not in jsfiddle '/show' which is why this was my original link. I don't know why and I don't know how to make the css rules that make it work inside jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

? Was useful to me for a lot of weird CSS stuff (but nothing to do with box-shadow).

And also, take a look at: http://cubiq.org/webkit-weird-box-shadow-bug-with-fix

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried '-webkit-appearance: none;', it doesn't work. The link doesn't help either. I set top: 0, left: 0 and still no shadow.